# How can I save my Oracle Toad connections to move to a new PC?

Tags: oracle, toad

I want to move to a new PC and take my Toad connections with me because I have a few and don't want to retype them all.

Comment: Please have a look at http://asktoad.com/DWiki/doku.php/faq/answers/general

Answer (score 17):

Copy the **%APPDATA%\Dell\Toad for Oracle\*VERSION*\User Files** folder to your new PC.

Ie.

C:\Users\*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\Dell\Toad for Oracle\*VERSION*\User Files

C:\Documents and Settings\*USERNAME*\Application Data\Dell\Toad for Oracle\*VERSION*\User Files

Beware: In older versions of Toad "Dell" in the path above used to be "Quest Software".

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData can be changed with %APPDATA%

Comment: Also note the location of your Oracle home is stored in the **Connections.ini** file and you will want to ensure that, that location is the same  on the new machine.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `%APPDATA%\Quest Software\Toad` for `Oracle\VERSION\User Files\` folder.
Copy the following files: `CONNECTIONACTIONS.INI` and `Connections.xml`, to the same folder in the new PC.

Ie. `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\13.2 Trial\User Files`

Answer (score 2):

You have to save your tnsnames.ora files of your respective oracle installations. Also, I believe TOAD uses the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to locate the TNS_NAMES.ORA it is using.

Comment: Agreed.  For the Oracle 9 client this file is located (assuming a default install location) at C:\oracle\ora92\network\ADMIN.  For later client versions the path might be slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

On the Old machine:
Menu> Session>New Connection

then Select all connections and Use the Export button(with a blue arrow pointing to Right Down - located at the top of the Pop up screen).

On the New machine:
Menu> Session>New Connection

then Use the Import button(with a blue arrow pointing UP - located at the top of the Pop up screen).

Comment: This feature was introduced in Toad 11, and consequently you can only import these files with Toad 11 and later versions.

Answer (score 2):

Toad 12.6 - 64 bit
coping the folders did not work for me.
Toad had new option- menu utilities-> copy user settings. this worked and imported user ids and password.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to note is that in your new computer folder destination as Evan specified (generally it is in the ADMIN folder, can you can search for ora format, pretty rare you have another file that format). If after installing Toad, there's already a tnsname.ora file exist, you have to do some work around:

1. copy and paste
2. if you run into troubles, back out of the folder, right click and select admin view (especially for windows 7 and vista)
3. that allows you to edit the file
4. if no pasting is allowed, just cut and move the existing tnsname.ora file and "cut" it out of the folder
5. then move the correct one in
6. generally you can now edit the tnsname.ora file outside of the ADMIN folder, feel free to open and then paste all the TNS Names.